# In maven, if I create a subpackage, how is the main package referenced?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ with a maven project.  I'm new to IntelliJ (and pretty much maven).  I created a new project and am building without issue, but I noticed when I create a new subpackage under java/, I can't import classes/interfaces declared in java/.

Do I need to explicitly declare the package name in the subpackage file?  What is this package path by default if not specified in the pom file?  Or is this the groupId?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `artifactId` and `groupId` values specified in the `pom.xml` have nothing to do with the actual classes.

They are used to help you categorize whole projects (jars), and have no influence in the classes or packages inside the projects.

Maven default folder structure:

```
src
|
|--main
|  |
|  |--java
|  |  |
|  |  |--com
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |--mypackage
|  |  |     |
|  |  |     |--MyClassA.java
|  |  |     |
|  |  |     |--submypackage
|  |  |        |
|  |  |        |--SomeOtherClass.java
|  |  |--net
|  |     |
|  |     |--netpackage
|  |        |
|  |        |--MyNetClassA.java
|  |
|  |--resources
|
|--test
   |
   |--java
   |  |
   |  |--com
   |     |
   |     |--anotherpackage
   |        |
   |        |--AnotherClassTest.java
   |
   |--resources
```

If you want to, from `MyNetClassA`, use `MyClassA`, you'll have something like:

`MyNetClassA.java` file contents:

```
package net.netpackage;

import com.mypackage.MyClassA;

public class MyNetClassA {
    MyClassA myField;
}
```

Same thing applies to **subpackages**: If you want to, from `MyClassA`, use `SomeOtherClass`, you'll have something like:

`MyClassA.java` file contents:

```
package com.mypackage;

import com.mypackage.subpackage.SomeOtherClass;

public class MyClassA {
    SomeOtherClass myOtherField;
}
```

**It does not matter if a package is declared below another package. You call it "subpackage", but, for Java, it is just a different package.**

Also, no class in `src/test/java` (such as `AnotherClassTest`) is accessible to any class in `src/main/java`.

On the other hand, any class in `src/main/java` **is** accessible to `src/test/java`.